# How to prevent Ghidra from removing unreachable blocks?

Tags: decompilation, ghidra, decompile

I am using this extension for loading PS-X executables:

https://github.com/lab313ru/ghidra_psx_ldr

During decompilation, Ghidra shows some of these warnings:

```
WARNING: Removing unreachable block (ram,0x8003a320)
```

Do you know how to prevent Ghidra from pruning these code blocks ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, there is a setting in Code Browser that allows Ghidra to eliminate unreachable code, you would have to change the setting by editing the options for Code Browser. This can be done by going to Edit -> Tools Options. This would bring you to a page as seen in the screenshot below

[image]

Under the Analysis options in the Decompiler folder, there is a checkbox called "Eliminate unreachable code", uncheck that and apply the option. I hope this helps!